# How to swap the position of two sprites?

Tags: java, android, cocos2d

I'm making a game like Candy Crush with Cocos2D in Android. I've made the sprites but I want to swap to sprites by touch .

How to swap the position of two sprites?

Comment: You'll need to edit the question to include information on how you're storing the objects represented by the sprites.

Comment: i’ve used a 2D-vector to store objects

Comment: What are you having trouble with? The switching? Detecting which ones to switch?

Comment: the switching .

Answer (score 2):

To do this, all that you need to write is something like this, a simple swap function:

```
class Point
{

private int x, y;

procedure swapPositions(Point a)
{
   Point temp = a;

   a.x = x;
   x = temp.x;

   a.y = y;
   y = temp.y;
}

}
```

Note: this is pseudo-code and it will not work if you try to use it. You must write your own, with this concept, and fit it into your current game's build.